# Debugging code to find longest palindrome in a string

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to understand a code fragment that finds the longest palindrome in a given string.  Here's the code segment

```
public static String longestPalindromeString(String in) {
        char[] input = in.toCharArray();
        int longestPalindromeStart = 0;
        int longestPalindromeEnd = 0;

        for (int mid = 0; mid < input.length; mid++) {
            // for odd palindrom case like 12321, 3 will be the mid
            int left = mid-1;
            int right = mid+1;
            // we need to move in the left and right side by 1 place till they reach the end
            while (left >= 0 && right < input.length) {
                // below check to find out if its a palindrome
                if (input[left] == input[right]) {
                    // update global indexes only if this is the longest one till now
                    if (right - left > longestPalindromeEnd
                            - longestPalindromeStart) {
                        longestPalindromeStart = left;
                        longestPalindromeEnd = right;
                    }
                }
                left--;
                right++;
            }
            // for even palindrome, we need to have similar logic with mid size 2
            // for that we will start right from one extra place
            left = mid-1;
            right = mid + 2;// for example 12333321 when we choose 33 as mid
            while (left >= 0 && right < input.length)
            {
                if (input[left] == input[right]) {
                    if (right - left > longestPalindromeEnd
                            - longestPalindromeStart) {
                        longestPalindromeStart = left;
                        longestPalindromeEnd = right;
                    }
                }
                left--;
                right++;
            }
        }
        // we have the start and end indexes for longest palindrome now
        return in.substring(longestPalindromeStart, longestPalindromeEnd + 1);
    }

}
```

However, the code segment seems to be failing for the inputs `"bb"` returns `"b"` and `"abb"` returns `"a"` instead of bb.

Any thoughts on whats causing the bug?

[Source](http://www.journaldev.com/530/java-program-to-find-out-longest-palindrome-in-a-string) for the code segment .

Comment: Your code fails on a very simple test case, as you say (`"bb"`). For such a simple case, it is very easy to go through the code by hand and see where it goes wrong. Failing that, you can use a debugger and set breakpoints and see where the data starts to deviate from what you expect.

Comment: The comments at the bottom of the page you found this on indicate what the bugs are.  It amazes me that the original author hasn't fixed it by now.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. @us2012, Ive tried debugging it, but when I try to fix one aspect of it, another stops working, so I thought Id get some help

Answer (score 1):

To fix this change the following:

1. In the while, add a break to break from the while once two characters are not equal.

   ```
   while(/*....*/)
   {
        if(/*...*/)
        {
            //....
        }
        else           // add this
            break;     // and this   
   }
   ```
2. The initial setting of left and right for the even case is wrong. It assumes that the mid two characters are the same. Change it to

   ```
   left = mid;
   right = mid+1;
   ```

This is exactly as what is stated in the comments of the original code... -_- which I just read.